# Is it possible to combine Search filter with FillterSet filter which lookup expression isn't `exact`?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to combine Search filter with FIlterSet filter which hasn't git standard lookup_expression.

I tried to add this configuration for my endpoint:

```
filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    search_fields = ('username', 'full_name')
    filterset_fields = 'username',
```

It works good but I need `startswith` lookup for `username` in `filterset_fields`

Here is my endpoint

```
class UsersAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreatorSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    search_fields = ('username', 'full_name')
    filterset_fields = 'username',
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    #filter_class = UserFilter
```

And my filter:

```
class UserFilter(filters.FilterSet, ):
    username = filters.CharFilter(field_name='username', lookup_expr='startswith')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = 'username',
```

If I'll start to use UserFilter than SearchFilter will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way,

```
filterset_fields = {
        'username': ['startswith'], 
    }
```